# Running Macro on multiple worksheets using prefix and copy data to other worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I am completely new in VBA , please excuse the silly questions ;)

**Background**
I am working on a worksheet with multiple tabs although I need to copy data from worksheets that start with only "2018 and 2017" and then paste it to summary tab.

**Details**
At Top of These sheet are headers and other calculation which i don't need to copy.(refer Row# 1 to 10 in attached snap shot)
From these sheets I wanted to copy range which is starting from row 13 but this row# can change sheet to sheet, so i have created two variable -
first select Cell(L1) and go XL down 
Second to select Range("L1048576").End(xlUp).Address
from there I am  selecting End xlToLeft to select the whole range and copy it-

**Problem**
I am not able to run this code using variable to select the range, if i select data range using cell reference example("A13:L26")its works fine but getting error while using variable to select the range.
Also is there a way by which I can exclude the headers?

**Below is my codes**

[image: Screenshot of a Worksheet]

```
Sub NEWWORK()
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim a As String
    Dim B As String

    a = Range("L1").End(xlDown).Address
    B = Range("L1048576").End(xlUp).Address

    Sheets("Summary").Activate

    For Each sheet In Worksheets
        If (Left(sheet.Name, 4) = "2018") Or (Left(sheet.Name, 4) = "2017") Then
            sheet.Select
            sheet.Range(a, B).Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Copy

            Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        End If
    Next sheet
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the range on each sheet - you need to do that *inside* the loop:

```
Sub NEWWORK()
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Sheets("Summary").Activate

    For Each sheet In Worksheets
        If (Left(sheet.Name, 4) = "2018") Or (Left(sheet.Name, 4) = "2017") Then

            With sheet
                Set rng = .Range(.Range("L1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0), _
                                  .Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp))
            End With

            With Worksheets("Summary")
                .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, 1).Value = rng.Value
            End With

        End If
    Next sheet

End Sub
```